# How could I set dom element props as result of calculation directly in template

Tags: angular7

I feel that it's simple, but can't clear understand. I need to calculate x,y & etc depend on index. "[ERROR ->]" - it's part of console.error message. Of course, i run code without this one.

```
<g *ngFor="let collection of ps.activeProject.collections; index as i"
     class="collection-group">
    <svg class="collection-header"
[ERROR ->]x="{{80 * i}}"
         y="20"
         height="351"
         width="220">
      <rect height="32" width="190"></rect>
      <text x="13" y="16" dy="4px"
            style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
        {{collection.name}}
      </text>
      <title>{{collection.name}}</title>
    </svg>
  </g>
```

Comment: Full error: Can't bind to 'x' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg'. ("
     class="collection-group">
    <svg class="collection-header"
         [ERROR ->]x="{{80 * i}}"
         y="20"
         height="351"
"): ng:///AppModule/PlateComponent.html@5:9

Comment: When i set x="80" it's all OK? ^_^ ?